# php app mailing function

Tags: php, email

I'm having a problem using a mailing function in a php ecomm app I purchased from envato. The developer has a mailer function which is used to send emails from the website. 
Function :

```
/*  Send mail with custom templates:$template : E-mail template.$array : Variables for email template. $subject : E-mail Subject.$to : E-mail receiver.*/

function mailing($template,$array,$subject,$to) {
    $cfg = DB::select('SELECT * FROM config WHERE id = 1')[0];
    $array['url'] = url('');
    $array['name'] = $cfg->name;
    $array['address'] = nl2br($cfg->address);
    $array['phone'] = $cfg->phone;
    $array['email'] = $cfg->email;
    // Get the template from the database
    $message = DB::select("SELECT template FROM templates WHERE code = '".$template."'")[0]->template;
    foreach ($array as $ind => $val) {
        $message = str_replace("{{$ind}}",$val,$message);
    }   
    $message = preg_replace('/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/is','',$message);
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$cfg->name.' <'.$cfg->email.'>'."\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    return true;
}
```

The email template is pulled from the db.

As part of the checkout process in the API.php file, the mailer function is used to email the order to the user with the follwing code:

```
// Send an email to customer
    mailing(
            'order',
            array(  'buyer_name'=>$data['name'],
                    'buyer_email'=>$data['email'],
                    'buyer_fields'=>$email_fields,
                    'name'=>$this->cfg->name,
                    'address'=>$this->cfg->address,
                    'phone'=>$this->cfg->phone,
                    'products'=>$email_products,
                    'total'=>$total
                ),
            'Order Confirmation #'.$order,
            $data['email']
        );
```

This is fine, however, I'm trying to get that to also send myself the email of the order as opposed to having to check the admin ux as is currently the way it works. Could anyone point me in the right direction ?

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: _Small note_ If you can read and understand it, then maybe you can debug it!

Comment: Just copy that mailing function call, and change buyer_email to your email adress hard coded and insert it directly after it.

Comment: annoying they didn't expose the BCC option in the function parameters. You could have just added your address as the BCC. If you don't mind exposing it you could just append it to the $to with a `;` separating the addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is to add another call to `mail()` an replace `$to` with your email address in the `mailing()` function.

But as this is probably used in more than one place in the app, it might be nice to add a parameter to this function that tells it to email to you as well as the intended recipient

```
function mailing($template,$array,$subject,$to, $toMe=false) {
    //      new parameter                       ^^^^^^^^^^^

    $cfg = DB::select('SELECT * FROM config WHERE id = 1')[0];
    $array['url'] = url('');
    $array['name'] = $cfg->name;
    $array['address'] = nl2br($cfg->address);
    $array['phone'] = $cfg->phone;
    $array['email'] = $cfg->email;
    // Get the template from the database
    $message = DB::select("SELECT template FROM templates WHERE code = '".$template."'")[0]->template;
    foreach ($array as $ind => $val) {
        $message = str_replace("{{$ind}}",$val,$message);
    }   
    $message = preg_replace('/\{\{(.*?)\}\}/is','',$message);
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: '.$cfg->name.' <'.$cfg->email.'>'."\r\n";
    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    // now mail yourself if $toMe is true
    if ( $toMe !== false ) {
        mail($toMe,$subject,$message,$headers);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Then anywhere in the app where it sends mail yo can add a request to get a copy of the email. BUT, if you dont add the new parameter, the `mailing()` function will act just as it did before.

```
// Send an email to customer
mailing(
        'order',
        array(  'buyer_name'=>$data['name'],
                'buyer_email'=>$data['email'],
                'buyer_fields'=>$email_fields,
                'name'=>$this->cfg->name,
                'address'=>$this->cfg->address,
                'phone'=>$this->cfg->phone,
                'products'=>$email_products,
                'total'=>$total
            ),
        'Order Confirmation #'.$order,
        $data['email'],
        'me@mymail.com'     // new parameter added
    );
```

Now none of the existing calls to `mailing` will be effected, because you used a default value in the function prototype, unless you add the extra parameter to the call to `mailing` but any of them you want to alter can be done easily, and as you specify the address when you want to get a copy, you can use any of your email addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another

```
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

line and replace `$to` with your email. That's it.